# Python pandas how to groupby column and perform count function without remove any duplicate row?

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have following table:

```
  id  Key  series_no
  0    B      a3
  1    B      t7
  2    A      u3
  3    A      p8
  2    A      7u
  1    B      zz
```

I would like to perform count function at column Key that will groupby id column. Below is my expected output

```
  id  Key  series_no   count
  0    B      a3        1
  1    B      t7        2
  2    A      u3        2
  3    A      p8        1
  2    A      7u        2
  1    B      zz        2
```

I have try below code but does not work for me:

```
 df["count"]=df["Key"].groupby(["id","Key"]).count()
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: `df["Key"].groupby(["id","Key"]).transform('count')`

Comment: Hi, it return me KeyError: 'Key'

Comment: df["Key"].groupby(["id"]).transform('count')

Comment: Hi @WeNYoBen for your information I need groupby Key also

Comment: df.groupby(["id"]).Key.transform('count')  run the code , i think this produce what you need